# Автоматическое открытие корзины OpenCart

Tags: javascript, opencart

Нужно сделать, чтобы при добавлении товара, автоматически открывалась корзина. Уже все перерыл, никак не могу понять, как подключить.

Корзина:

```js
var cart = {
  'addcart': function(product_id, quantity) { 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

        if (json['redirect']) {
          location = json['redirect'];
        }

        if (json['success']) {

          $('#notification').html('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
          setTimeout(function() {
          $("#notification").fadeOut()}, 2300);
          // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
          $('#cart').addClass('cart-top open');
          $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
          $('#cart #cart-total').html(json['total']);

          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

          $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
      }
    });
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart-top" class="cart-right">
              <div class="cart-top">
                  
<div id="cart" class="clearfix">
    <div data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Загрузка..." class="heading media dropdown-toggle">      
      <div class="cart-inner media-body">
        <a>
          <i class="icon-cart"></i>
          <div class="wrap-cart">
            <b class="text-cart">Корзина покупок</b><br>
            <span id="cart-total" class="cart-total">Товаров: 8 (480.00руб.)</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>            
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu content">
            <li>
        <table class="table">
                    <tbody><tr>
            <td class="text-center">              <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="AmazonBasics Ultra-Portable Mini Bluetooth Speaker" title="TEST"></a>
              </td>
            <td class="text-left"><a href="#">TEST</a>
                                          <br>
              8 x <b>480.00руб.</b>
            </td>

            <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="cart.remove('256');" title="Удалить" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
          </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-v4">
                        <tbody><tr>
              <td class="text-right"><strong>Сумма</strong></td>
              <td class="text-right">480.00руб.</td>
            </tr>
                      </tbody></table>
          <p class="text-center view-cart">
            <a href="#">
              Просмотр корзины            </a>
            <a href="#">
              Оформление заказа</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
          </ul>
</div>
              </div>
          </div>
```